# Is there any difference between "mutating" function and "inout" parameters in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, struct, inout, mutating-function

As per Swift documentation both mutating and inout keywords are used to modify the value types from within a function. Is there any difference between "mutating" and "inout" and any special case where we need to use either of them.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`mutating` marks a method. `inout` marks a parameter. They are completely different things.

Methods marked with `mutating` can mutate `self` i.e. set properties of `self`, reassign `self` etc.

```
struct Foo {
    var foo: Int

    mutating func mutate() {
        foo += 1 // this is mutating self
    }
}
```

Parameters marked with `inout` basically become `var` variables, as opposed to `let` constants. You can change them, and the changes will also reflect on the caller's side.

```
func f(_ x: inout Int) {
    x = 10
}

var a = 1
f(&a)
print(a) // 10
```

Comment: `Parameters marked with inout basically become var variables, as opposed to let constants. ` — quite a bit disagree, because `Swift` used to have `var` *mark* for function parameters, and it was different thing. Parameters with `var` were allowed to mutate, but all the changes never left scope of function, changes of `inout` params were *put back* into variable passed into function.

Comment: @user28434 that’s why I also wrote the next sentence.

Comment: And I quoted part about `basically become var variables`. Because there were both `var` and `inout`, and they were different things, calling one using keyword of another is confusing.

Answer (score 3):

For me I see difference just in places where they are used.

Parameter marked with `inout` keyword allows you to pass your value to any method similary as reference

```
func square(inout num: Int) { 
    num = num * num
}
```

In contrast to it, method marked with `mutating` keyword is used in type scope and allows you to change value itself from this method

```
extension Int {

    mutating func square() {
        self = self * self
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Value types' instance methods cannot change the value type's properties (or value itself), unless they are marked as `mutating`.

Functions of any kind cannot change their parameters (and have the change propagate outside the function) unless those parameters are marked as `inout`.

They do a similar job, but in different contexts.

Answer (score 1):

inout:- It means that modifying the local variable will also modify the passed-in parameters. Without it, the passed-in parameters will remain the same value.

mutating:-The properties of value types cannot be modified within its instance methods by default. In order to modify the properties of a value type, you have to use the mutating keyword in the instance method.